# How to create Android proximity alert with question intent and store answers?

Tags: proximity

If anyone can please help me I would greatly appreciate it (in simple noob language please!), I cant seem to find a solution online.

I need to make an Android app which shows a proximity alert when the user enters a specific area, then asks the user a question to redirect them to 5 more questions (if they click yes) and then store their answers to be viewed later.

Im really new to programming and have been trying to do this for ages with no luck now

Thank you all in advance!